# Reading Json file as input for a request payload

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured

I was trying to understand the below code where a Json file/property is being used as a payload for a Request, however due to use of Jayway not able to understand it fully. Can someone help me understand the code here better?

```
    private static final Configuration configuration =
              Configuration.builder()
                  .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
                  .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
                  .build();
        
          @SneakyThrows
          public static JsonObject verifyUser(
              String a, String b, String c) {
        
            DocumentContext parsed =
                JsonPath.parse(new File("path.json"));
            parsed =
                JsonPath.using(configuration)
                    .parse(parsed.jsonString())
                    .set("a", id)
                    .set("b", nfo)
                    .set("c", finalId);
  if (b != null) {
      parsed =
          JsonPath.using(configuration)
              .parse(parsed.jsonString())
              .set("b", code);
    }
    return new Gson().fromJson(parsed.jsonString(), JsonObject.class);
  }
```